# Using Ajax to display CSS and HTML from external webpage

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, architecture

I am developing a portfolio website. A friend of mine happens to have a lot of the same projects and hackathons. To make it easier to manage, we are going to host the 'Blog' data on one website and both me and him want to display the data on our domains. We are trying to use ajax for this. Here is my current code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#box").load("http://individual.utoronto.ca/jollyredflames/ #Education");
    });
});
```

This is just a tester to get a simple text element which points to an `<h2>Education</h2>`. However, the code above does not retrieve this content. I believe this is due to some error in writing the URL to tell it to go to an external page (very similar code to get content from the local domain works fine). How can I fix this code?

Is there a better plugin or architecture so both me and my friend can pull from a common blog and host it on our individual websites?

Thank You

Comment: `https://http://individual.utoronto.ca/jollyredflames/` ... ?

Comment: You can use `https://` or `http://` not both, and there's a space at the end of the url.

Comment: sorry that is just a pasting error! I made the edit

Comment: @haldo the space at the end is part of the method. It returns only the ID tag Education by using this format